# UINavigationBar setBackgroundImage in AppDelegate with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, appdelegate

I am trying to set a background image to the navigation bar globally in the App Delegate in Swift.
I can get it to work on an individual View Controller like this:

```
var topBar: UINavigationBar!

topBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "navbar"), forBarMetrics:
.Default)
```

But when I try and add the following to the App Delegate, it crashes with an uncaught exception:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:
"navbar"), forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

Comment: Check if you have an image set named `navbar` in your image assets.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Another reason why it might not work could be that you don't have a Navigation Controller as an initial view controller.

Comment: I do have and image set named navbar.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I deleted the navigation bars and added new ones in the storyboard... now it works with just the App Delegate code. It's just Xcode 6/Swift being buggy, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add These Two Lines In app delegte

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

let navBackgroundImage:UIImage! = UIImage(named: "navbar.png")

UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(navBackgroundImage, for: .default)}
```