# How to set image for Navigation bar AppDelegate Swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, swift2, appdelegate

I found a bunch of links on SO that show how to set the navigation bar to an image in Objective-C, but none in swift. The one I did find, didn't help: [UINavigationBar setBackgroundImage in AppDelegate with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26723989/uinavigationbar-setbackgroundimage-in-appdelegate-with-swift)

In the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in the `AppDelegate` I'm attempting to do this with swift with no avail:

```
    let headerImage = UIImage(named: "header.png")
    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(headerImage, forBarMetrics:.Default)
     UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.Default

    var navigationVC:UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: tableVC)
    let frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    window = UIWindow(frame: frame)

    window!.rootViewController = navigationVC
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

How can I set the navigation bar to an image in swift?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're code is fine. The problem lies in the image itself. Are you sure you added it to your target? Debug `headerImage` and make sure it is not `nil`

Comment: How do I make sure I added it to my target? http://postimg.org/image/pw1x4olrj/ Presumably by this image `header.png` is in the right place... When setting breakpoints on `headerImage` and the line below the app crashes giving me a llDB error. @joern

Comment: Select your image and open the Utilities view. Make sure there is a checkmark under Target Membership. Here is a screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/x0027l3nh/

Comment: Same thing... http://postimg.org/image/6tkqp1wm5/

Comment: Have you tried another image?

Comment: Ok, very weird. When using another image it works.  I just deleted, put in in the trash, and then added it again and it doesn't work. Any ideas what could be wrong with that specific image?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94706/discussion-between-lukesivi-and-joern).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a retina image but Xcode does not know that because it does not have a file name that contains `@2x`.

So if you rename your image to `header@2x.png` it works.

You might want to consider using an Asset Catalog for your images to avoid things like this.